# в Stream получить List

Tags: java, потоки-данных

имеются некоторые Paymentы от одного аккаунта другому, нужно получить: сколько раз каждый аккаунт получал Payment.
По коду:
группирую list по получателям, дальше из мапы получаю ключ, формирую list из AccountInfo, **key.hashCode() - заглушка**, по факту вместо этой заглушки нужно получить value.size() - тут и застрял

```
public AccountInfo(Account account, Integer count) {
    this.account = account;
    this.count = count;
}

List<AccountInfo> accountInfoList = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Payment::getTo))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .map(key -> new AccountInfo(key, key.hashCode()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее проще было бы сразу рассчитать частоту платежей для счёта-получателя, используя `Collectors.groupingBy` и `Collectors.summingInt`, а затем преобразовать элементы мапы:

```java
List<Payment> list = getPayments(); // входной лист платежей

Map<Account, Integer> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Payment::getTo,
            Collectors.summingInt(p -> 1)
        ));

List<AccountInfo> result = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new AccountInfo(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

В принципе, и показанное решение можно слегка изменить для желаемого результата:

```java
List<AccountInfo> result = list
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Payment::getTo)) // Map<Account, List<Payment>>
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new AccountInfo(e.getKey(), e.getValue().size()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: как же близок я был к верному решению =)